# formatting raw data into appropriate xml

Tags: xml

I am trying to convert this into xml format. Not clear with the actioncode.

```
SyncDeliveredQuantities/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:CreationDateTime/
SyncDeliveredQuantities/DataArea/oa:Sync/oa:ActionCriteria/oa:ActionExpression @actionCode
SyncDeliveredQuantities/DataArea/DeliveredQuantities/oa:CustomerParty/oa:PartyIDs/oa:ID
SyncDeliveredQuantities/DataArea/DeliveredQuantities
```

I am sorry if my question is incomplete. I have no other information apart from this.

EDIT:
From the reply below, i can image this to be something like this:

```
    <SyncDeliveredQuantities> 
            <oa:ApplicationArea />
            <oa:CreationDateTime />

        <DataArea>

            <oa:Sync />
            <oa:ActionCriteria />        
            <oa:ActionExpression actionCode="" />

            <DeliveredQuantities>                        
                            <oa:CustomerParty />
                            <oa:PartyIDs />
                            <oa:ID/> 
            </DeliveredQuantities>

      </DataArea > 

    </SyncDeliveredQuantities>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is a great language for representing data with one-to-one and hierarchical relationships.

When you have decided that you want to use XML to store your data you need to generate a schema for the document structure.

How? Well you are going to need a good understanding of your data. I can't tell you much about the data you have provided, but it looks a lot like XPath (the xml query language) so I can work a bit out. The good news is that it will map very nicely to XML!

You want to rebuild the file structure from these queries. The common top level is `SyncDeliveredQuantities`, so you will need an element for that. This is called the root.

```
<SyncDeliveredQuantities/>
```

The forward slashes represent a parent-child relationship. We can see that our root has 2 children, `oa:ApplicationArea` and `DataArea`. The `oa:` portion is a namespace prefix - these are important to preserve. Now we have the following structure.

```
<SyncDeliveredQuantities>
    <oa:ApplicationArea/>
    <DataArea/>
</SyncDeliveredQuantities>
```

Great! That might be enough for you to work out a lot of the structure. But what about the `@` sign? This is an attribute and you will first encounter it in the element `oa:ActionExpression`. This element will contain an attribute when written in XML:

```
<oa:ActionExpression actionCode="code"/>
```

Unfortunately, I can't tell you what type of data should be in that attribute :(

**EDIT**
There are 2 things missing from your XML the first is an xml document definition (not needed). The second is the definition of the `oa` namespace prefix!

You will need to add this attribute to the **root** element.

```
xmlns:oa="this_is_the_oa_namespace"
```

You will need to make sure you replace the attribute value with the correct namespace (if there is one) but from the sample you posted we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Thanks @gusdor. From your reply i formatted the xml. Do you think its nearly correct ? Thanks again for your fast response.

Comment: That looks great. There is one this missing that I forgot to cover, ill edit it in!

Comment: Thanks Man. I am really blind in this area. Appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Any time. Check out this XML tutorial if you are unfamiliar with it! http://www.w3schools.com/xml/